# Issues installing packages to attach Pro

Tags: 20.04

I haven't used my Ubuntu Pro account in a few months and before I never had an issue attaching a host.  I am stuck in the 1st step of installing the ubuntu-advantage-tools packages, it now refers to other packages to install ubuntu-pro-client and ubuntu-advantage-pro.  Even then, it gives a message that [Not candidate version].  It's Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Did something change with the process in the past 2 months, before was installing the one package and then attaching to your pro account with a token.  I can't even get past installing the first package.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Nothing has changed. Please edit your question to show us actual output. Summaries are too vague to offer useful advice.

Comment: root@xxxx:/etc/apt# sudo apt install ubuntu-advantage-tools                        Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package ubuntu-advantage-tools is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  ubuntu-pro-client ubuntu-advantage-pro

E: Package 'ubuntu-advantage-tools' has no installation candidate
root@xxxx:/etc/apt#

Comment: I did do a test to see if I could install the ubuntu-advantage-tools on a vanilla Ubuntu Desktop vm and it worked fine.  Same that it installs on a vanilla ubuntu server vm.

Comment: Sources file and sources dir, same.  apt updates fine.  We don't do a full apt upgrade as we only do the necessary packages that are vulnerabilities using Nessus/Scap scans.

Comment: Please avoid commenting on your own question. To add new information or clarification, [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1508093/edit) instead.